# Key Pressing in ProcessingJS Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, html, processing, embed, processing.js

I have a ProcessingJS project, and I put it on a local HTML page. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/processing-js/processing-js/v1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="processing-canvas">
size(400,400);
background(141,141,141);
keyPressed = function() {
        if(key+"" === "82" || key+"" === "114"){ // "r" or "R"
            text("Hi", 10,10);
        }
        return;   
};
</script>
<canvas id="processing-canvas"> </canvas>

</html>
```

For some reason, when I open the HTML page, I can see everything working (As in I see the grey background) well, but nothing happens when I click the 'r' or 'R' buttons. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out! What I was doing is I was writing

```
keyPressed=fuction(){
   // CODE
};
```

However, I should've been writing:

```
void keyPressed(){
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look correct:

```
if(key+"" === "82" || key+"" === "114"){
```

From [the Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/key/), that should be this:

```
if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
```

I'm not sure why you're trying to compare `String` values in your code, but it might have something to do with [JavaScript not having a `char` datatype](http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#nochartype):

> JavaScript only knows about numbers, and strings, unlike Java, which also knows about "char" data types. The char is a 16 bit unsigned integer value, that can also pretend to be a letter (from the ISO8859-1 codepage for the first 256 numbers, and basically magic after that). Unfortunately, as JavaScript has no equivalent, relying on char comparisons to be either numbers or letters is quite likely to cause problems. If you have Processing code where you're comparing chars, you will either have to perform int casting, or string casting, using the int() and str() functions, so that you know you're explicitly comparing datatypes that JavaScript can deal with.

But I don't think you're doing the conversion correctly. You could try using the `int()` or `str()` functions (again, [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/) is your best friend) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A processing canvas by default has to be written in java, if you want to write it in javascript, this is possible with a little bit of extra html:

```
    <head>
      <script src="processing.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas1 width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      <script id="script1" type="text/javascript">
        function sketchProc(processing) {
          //Code goes here
          processing.draw = function() {
            //This is the draw function
          }
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        // attaching the sketchProc function to the canvas
        var p = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
        // p.exit(); to detach it
      </script>
    </body>
```